# Java - Could not find or load main class - Only on Linux

Tags: java, linux, shell, javac

I've built a class named `ConvertToPdf`, and used the following commands to compile&run it :

```
javac -cp C:/Users/Itamar/Desktop/JARs/aspose-cells.jar;C:/Users\Itamar/Desktop/JARs/aspose-slides.jar;C:/Users\Itamar/Desktop/JARs/aspose-words.jar ConvertToPdf.java

java -cp .;C:/Users/Itamar/Desktop/JARs/aspose-cells.jar;C:/Users/Itamar/Desktop/JARs/aspose-slides.jar;C:/Users/Itamar/Desktop/JARs/aspose-words.jar ConvertToPdf
```

It worked just fine on Windows, but when I tried to run the same commands in Linux (I've replaced the `;` with `:` as needed ),the first one with the `javac` also works fine , but the second ends with : `Could not find or load main class`.
I'd like to know what changes I have to make in order to make it run properly. I'd be grateful if anyone could point me to the solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: what command are you using in Linux?

Comment: What are the exact command lines you used on unix?

Comment: @Andreas, I've edited the question , replaced "\" by "/" as also needed.Hope it more clear right now.

Comment: Do you actually have a directory named `C:`?

Comment: The "C:" in a question about linux reminds me of this: http://xkcd.com/278/

Comment: No, I DO NOT have C: on linux, the path itself is not the problem - if it was , the first command would not run at all. Useful answers are welcomed

Comment: @Itamar Don't just hint vaguely at what you ran on Linux. Post the actual commands.

Comment: @Itamar `the path itself is not the problem` - if you are using any classes from the referenced jar files in your `ConvertToPdf.java`, then it is. Otherwise the java compiler (and also the launcher) will simply ignore those jar files it can not find. If the command line in your question is now accurate, your issue is that you have `.;` as part of the classpath - use `.:` instead (note the colon). When using the `-cp` parameter, you **must** explicitly pass the current directory if it contains required classes - without `-cp`, `java` would search the current directory automatically.

Answer (score 4):

In Unix you need to use `/` instead of `\`

```
java -cp .:/Users/Itamar/Desktop/JARs/aspose-cells.jar:/Users/Itamar/Desktop/JARs/aspose-slides.jar:/Users/Itamar/Desktop/JARs/aspose-words.jar ConvertToPdf
```

Comment: Also done it of course. If I didn't the first command would not run at all :) But thanks for the answer

Comment: Where exactly is your main class located?

Comment: Both the ConvertToPdf.java and the ConvertToPdf.class files are located in the same class from which i'm running the shell. Just to mentioned I've successfully opened the ConvertToPdf.class file to edit from the shell.

Comment: But there is no `C:` in Unix. Are you sure your classpath is correct under Unix?

Comment: @Itamar: Did it work for you?